# PHP site preventing XSS a bit too wel

Tags: php, xss, htmlspecialchars

I have a blog system where random people can post comments. If naughty people try to post Javascript, this will happen:

```
bla bla <script>alert("Hacked")</script>
```

Turns into

```
bla bla &lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Hacked&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;
```

I would prefer the post to keep the code intact, just in case someone ever needs to post HTML. How do I make the second line look like the first, without it actually doing anything? The current way I filter it is:

```
$safeMessage = htmlspecialchars($reply['message'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');

echo "$safeMessage";
```

Comment: Huh? The way you do it is *exactly* the right approach to this - when displayed in the browser, it should show `<script>alert("Hacked")</script>` Can you clarify what is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the code intact?" By definition, you cannot both filter out HTML characters which might be unsafe and allow them through at the same time. If you mean simply display it, so it displays the actual HTML (not rendered HTML), then what's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: Maybe you're once encoding it (to the second line) and then setting an element's `.textContent` (`.text` in jQ) to it? Using `.textContent` escapes code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way I can think of is using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and specify only a subset of HTML you want to allow. Check documentation [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs)